# Callable Interface: TypeName throws nullpointer Exception calling external Package Content

Tags: apex, callable

Implementing Callable Interface as described from Salesforce:

```
global with sharing class XXX_Callable implements Callable {


 // Dispatch actual methods
    global Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
      System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'Got Into Callable Method with Action: ' + action);
      switch on action {
        when 'processCallable' {
          return this.processCallable(args);
        }
        when else {
          throw new CallableException('Unknown Method \'' + action + '\'');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Created 2nd Generation Package and installed in Sandbox.

Calling Callable

```
            Callable extension = (Callable) Type.forName('NAMESPACE.XXX_Callable).newInstance();
            Boolean result = (Boolean) extension.call('processCallable', callableArgs);
```

First line fails with Nullpointer-Exception though Classes are visible within Sandbox. Also tried with forName(Namespace,Name) - same Issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of CallableException-Class which is NOT global!
Accidently forgot to define Class as global.